# How is a data-only container in Docker getting data?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, containers

I'm new to Docker and have read a lot about data-only container the last days. But I still have a question of understanding, how it works. :)

I have an `app` container (where the app is running) and an `app-data` container (where the files of the app are stored).

The `app-data` volume is created by 
`docker create -v /app-data --name app-data some/image`

The `app` container is created by 
`docker run -d -P --name app --volumes-from="app-data" some/image`

How did `app-data` get his files? How do I keep it in sync with my `host/directory/where/i/develop/my/apps`?
 I thought I should not do things like `-v host/directory/:/app-data:rw`, cause the portability. But that's the only way for me right now to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance! (:
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How did app-data get his files?

It will get any file created when editing in `/app-data` in the container `app`.
`app-data` stores its files in `/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/xxx`.

> How do I keep it in sync with my host/directory/where/i/develop/my/apps?

In that case, you wouldn't use a data volume container, you would mount direct the host folder in `app`, without using `app-data`.

Comment: Now i get it! Thanks. (:

Comment: You *could* still use a data volume container to store your data and keep it in sync with other means; e.g: rsync, dropbox, s3, etc.

Comment: @JamesMills I agree. As an aside, I wonder if `docker commit + docker save` is able to produced a tarred version which includes the volume...

Comment: It probably would work as long as your "data volume container" wasn't created from an image that contained the ``VOLUME`` instructions on the path where you are storing data :)